# Are there any seasonal or diurnal trends in earthquakes?

Tags: earthquakes, seasons, diurnal-cycle

Though I imagine it's unlikely there is any significant correlation because daily and annual temperature variation really only impact a fairly shallow layer of the crust, I wondered whether the actual data backs that up.  I could envision a few unlikely causes, such as the expansion\contraction, rainfall amounts, or crazy things like the little differences in earth-sun distance.  So what say you?

Comment: https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn28235-deepest-earthquakes-seem-to-be-seasonal-but-we-dont-know-why/ suggests such a trend occurs (in the month following the vernal and autumnal equinox). If you want to do your own study, http://www.emsc-csem.org/ would be an excellent resource (if you actually do this, feel free to contact me for help, this sounds vaguely interesting).

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight tendency for earthquakes in coastal areas to coincide with higher gravitational attraction. In one study in Greece, earthquakes were 15% more likely to occur when the sun's gravitational pull was at a maximum. In general though, seismic-tidal correlations are very weak (but not zero).

Comment: Do you happen to know of\have links to the study?